# Can you choose which child process receives a message from a parent?

Tags: c, linux, fork, ipc

Below I have code of a parent process creating two child processes that belong to it. 
Now, I know I can make it so that the parent can write to a child process and the child process can read from it using read() and write().

My question is, is it possible for the parent to choose in this code below which child to write to? For example I asked the user of the program if he  wanted to write to child process 1 or child process 2 with their own supplied message, how would I go about that?

```
int p1[2];
int p2[2];
pid_t child_a, child_b;

 if(pipe(p1) == -1){
        printf("error in creating pipe\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(pipe(p2) == -1){
        printf("error in creating pipe\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

child_a = fork();

if (child_a == 0) {
    /* Child A code */
} else {
    child_b = fork();

    if (child_b == 0) {
        /* Child B code */
    } else {
        /* Parent Code */
    }
}
```

Comment: Pick one of the pipes for child_a (say p1) and  the other for child_b (say p2). Parent closes read end of both pipes. child_a closes write end of p1 and both ends of p2. child_b closes read end of p2 and both ends of p1. child_a reads p1[0], child_b reads p2[0].  Parent writes to p1[1] if want to send to child_a and p2[1] for child_b.

Comment: @kaylum thanks! although i did not ask this question before?

Comment: Sorry, may have mistaken you for someone else doing the same assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already created two pipes, so you're on the right track. You can use one pipe, say `p1`, to send messages from the parent to `child_a`, and use `p2` to send messages to `child_b`.

You can use `dup2` to switch the stdin file descriptor for a

```
int p1[2];
int p2[2];
pid_t child_a, child_b;

 if(pipe(p1) == -1){
        printf("error in creating pipe\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(pipe(p2) == -1){
        printf("error in creating pipe\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

child_a = fork();

if (child_a == 0) {
    /* Child A code */
    // now can read from stdin to receive messages from parent process
    dup2(p1[0], STDIN_FILENO); 
    // don't forget to close file descriptors that are open in every process!
    close(p1[0]); close(p1[1]);
} else {
    child_b = fork();

    if (child_b == 0) {
        /* Child B code */
        dup2(p2[0], STDIN_FILENO); 
        close(p2[0]); close(p2[1]); 
    } else {
        /* Parent Code */
        // Write something to child A
        write(p1[1], some_text, num_bytes);
        // Write something to child B
        write(p2[1], some_other_text, num_other_bytes);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that `write` takes an `int` file descriptor, a `void*` buffer to write -- which can be a `char*`, and an `int` number of bytes to write to the file descriptor.

Here's the `write` documentation from the POSIX API: https://linux.die.net/man/2/write

And here's the documentation for `dup2`: https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2

Comment: why is this not allowing user input? it just terminates when i put in my buffer and buffer size in the write().

Comment: To actually process input, you need to `read` from stdin in Child A or Child B. Without a read statement, you're just writing to a file descriptor and then closing all your processes.